# shopify app for adding title and short description for collection page

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

in Shopify . I need to build an app. The requirement is I need to add title and short description for the collection page. i can handle the backed. when we add title and short description from the application it should show in the collection page. it should not depend on the theme. it means what theme you use title and short description should be show on the top of the collection page. how can i do that i need guidelines and steps

I need guidelines, steps, and if there is a way for inserting my title and short description for  collection page for every theme .

Answer (score 0):

Check shopify theme app extensions and concretely - App embed blocks. The shopify documentation is very good on that.
https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/online-store/theme-app-extensions

You can basically create a App Embed block, that will be embedded in the  tag of every shop page.